# Infinite recursion when trying to make a recursive counter

Tags: ruby

I am trying to recursively increment @counter instance variable of a CounterClass, but every time #incrementer method is called @counter is set to 0 again, resulting in a infinite recursion.

What am I doing wrong? (I guess that @counter variable is never updated)

```
class CounterClass
  attr_accessor :counter

  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end
end

def incrementer(arg)
  cc ||= CounterClass.new

  cc.counter += 1
  p cc.counter
  incrementer(cc) unless cc.counter == 10
end
incrementer(CounterClass.new)
```

Comment: Why do you create a new instance of `CounterClass` every time? That's what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also, you're not using `arg`

Comment: If you do that to learn recursion, you picked a terrible terrible exercise. Try something with lists instead. Like finding length of a singly-linked list.

Comment: @sergio what is a singly-linked list?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: [singly-linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class CounterClass
  attr_accessor :counter

  def initialize
    @counter = 0
  end

  def incrementer
    @counter += 1
    incrementer unless @counter == 10
  end
end

obj = CounterClass.new
obj.incrementer
p obj.counter #=> 10
```

Comment: Note that in the original code, `incrementer` is a "free function".